# Compress file to tgz with apache camel

Tags: apache-camel

I want to compress a file to ".tgz" extension using apache camel 3.11.1.

As the [gzip](https://camel.apache.org/components/2.x/dataformats/gzip-dataformat.html#:%7E:text=The%20GZip%20Data%20Format%20is,by%20popular%20gzip%20%2F%20gunzip%20tool.) format is not supported, I tried [GZipDeflater](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.11.x/dataformats/gzipdeflater-dataformat.html) data format but it is not working (the file remains unchanged).

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, maybe it can help someone else.

The solution was to use `gzipDeflater` `DataFormat`, and explicitly provide the extension in the file endpoint when producing the result:

```
from("file:...../in?noop=true")
.marshal().gzipDeflater()
    .to("....../out1?fileName=${file:name.noext}.tgz");
```